# how to find the count of substring in string using BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to find how many times "fizz" appears in "fizzbuzzfizz" string in bigquery or sql.
here output should be 2.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly. What have your tried for example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL` and `ARRAY_LENGTH`, See this sql:

```
WITH data AS(
  SELECT 'fizzbuzzfizz' as string
  )

SELECT
  ARRAY_LENGTH(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(string, "fiz")) AS size FROM data;
```

Which produces this:

[image]